# c# Screna: How do I define screen area?

Tags: c#, video, screen-recording, screna

Im quite new to C# and Im building a small screen recording app.

Im using Screna nuget package and it works great.

Here is my basic code:

```
// Initialize an IImageProvider
            provider = new WindowProvider(); // Capture the entire Desktop

            // Initialize AviWriter
            videoWriter = new AviWriter("output.avi", provider, AviCodec.MotionJpeg);
```

The problem is that I want to record only a special area of screen, lets say top 10 px, left, px, 300 px wide and 300 px high.

But in my code, the WindowProvider() caputres the whole screen.

So, what do I have to do here?

Comment: it looks like you pass it a `IImageProvider`.

Comment: thanks, but what kind of params ?

Answer (score 3):

Screna now includes a RegionProvider which takes a System.Drawing.Rectangle.

Replace the usage of WindowProvider with RegionProvider.

```
new RegionProvider(new Rectangle(10,10,300,300));
```